# Using variables and returning a value inside an IBM DB2 BEGIN block Via ODBC

Tags: db2, odbc

In a nutshell I need to select the resulting value from a column value of max date with the year portion replaced with year-1.

However, the "date" column is NUMERIC(8,0) with values stored as yyyymmdd.  There is a separate "year" column - NUMERIC(4,0) - that stores just the yyyy value.  (FYI - I didn't create this table but I have to work with it as-is)

Without using variables and logic I can manually create a select statement that produces the desired results knowing that the current year is 2018, eg:

```
 SELECT REPLACE( MAX(MYDATE), 2018, 2017 ) FROM MYTABLE
```

I need to dynamically provide the values for the 2018 (max year) and 2017 (max year - 1) parameters.

This is what I have so far:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE VOUT CHAR;
DECLARE VYEAR CHAR;
SELECT MAX(MYYEAR) INTO VYEAR FROM MYTABLE;
SELECT REPLACE( MAX(MYDATE), @VYEAR, @VYEAR-1 ) INTO VOUT FROM MYTABLE;
END
```

I am getting the following error:

```
 [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0206 - Column or global variable @VYEAR not found.
```

If I remove the @VYEAR and @VYEAR-1 variables and hard code the 2018, 2017 values the statement block runs without error.

Also,  I have no idea how to retrieve the VOUT variable value. How do I go about getting that value from the client that is executing this ?

The only thing I have found is something like this:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line( 'Hello' );
END;
```

But I get this error:

```
 [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0199 - Keyword ON not expected.
```

Comment: You are declaring `VYEAR` and then reference `@VYEAR` -- why? These are two different identifiers.

Comment: Thanks, can you share the correct way to identify that variable ?

Comment: If a person's name is Drew, the correct way to address that person in writing is "Drew", not "@Drew" or "*^%%#&*Drew". This concept also applies to programming language identifiers. You seem to be following this logic with `VOUT`, why do you think `VYEAR` needs different treatment?

Comment: what your asking....

Comment: @danny117 mustacio clarified half of the question but I am still looking for an answer on how to retrieve the VOUT value from the client side.